# .net equivalent for php preg_replace

Tags: c#, php, regex

What is the c#.net equivalent for php's preg_replace function?

php code is like this:

```
    const ALLOW_VALUES = '[^a-z0-9àáâäèéêëìíîïòóôöùûŵýÿyÁÂÄÈÉÊËÌÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÛÜŴYÝ]';

    public function streetTownHash($data, $hashCheck = false, $updateRecord = false)
     {
       foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        try{
         $value = mb_convert_case($value, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
         } catch(Exception $e) {
          echo "Requires extension=php_mbstring.dll enabled !  - $e";
         }
        $valueConcat .= preg_replace('/'.self::ALLOW_VALUES.'/','',$value); # Remove punctuation etc
       }
       $streetTownHash =  sha1($valueConcat);

....
```

Edit: now is like so.

```
    private readonly SHA1 hash = SHA1.Create();
    private readonly Regex PunctuationStripper = new Regex(@"[^a-z0-9àáâäèéêëìíîïòóôöùûŵýÿyÁÂÄÈÉÊËÌÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÛÜŴYÝ]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    public string HashString(string value)
    {
        value = value.ToLower();
        value = PunctuationStripper.Replace(value, string.Empty);
        var bytes = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        var hashed = hash.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(hashed);
    }
```

Edit:

Would the regex expression need to change also?

Comment: Can you describe what preg_replace function does? I don't know php.

Comment: In .NET you should use `\p{L}` instead of `àáâäèé…`....

Comment: not totally sure.. fuzzy head day.. regex suff i imagine http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @KennyTM would expand a bit and put into an answer and i'll upvote. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class.

For example:

```
static readonly Regex PunctuationStripper = new Regex(@"[^a-z0-9àáâäèéêëìíîïòóôöùûŵýÿyÁÂÄÈÉÊËÌÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÛÜŴYÝ]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//...
value = PunctuationStripper.Replace(value, "");
```